# Not getting Acceptance for correct answers

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I'm very frustrated that some users accept my answers by commenting or upvoting but don't bother to mark the question as Accepted.
I think it also has to do with the fact that they have to wait 10 minutes until they can click the checkmark to accept the answer.

Also, take a look at the **bounty board**. This place is full of old questions with wonderful answers, some have many votes, and still, are considered "unanswered".

Are there any plans to maybe remind users to accept answers in questions they asked and they maybe upvoted? Perhaps create a badge for accepting answers?

Comment: It may help to separate the concept of unanswered from unaccepted if you view accepting an answer as just awarding a mini-bounty.

Comment: see also: [Can we flog a member who never ever, ever accepts answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298447/can-we-flog-a-member-who-never-ever-ever-accepts-answers)

Comment: There's really no way for you to know for sure if an upvote came from the person who asked the question.

Comment: The [Scholar badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/10/scholar) is awarded when the OP asks a question AND accepts an answer.  So, there's already a badge for that.

Answer (score 15):

> Are there any plans to maybe remind users to accept answers IN questions they asked AND they maybe upvoted ?

No.

Users are not required to accept an answer. They never have been and we don't plan on changing that.

Comment: But still - the question remains unanswered... Look at the huge amount of unanswered questions, which have a valid solution actually accepted by the asking user.

Comment: @KobyDouek Why is that a problem?  (And note that the site defines a question as being answered if it has an answer with a positive score, even if it is not accepted.)

Comment: To me - unanswered questions are questions without an answer. but that's just me...

Comment: And yet. The point of the accept is to indicate that "that answer helped me most" (from the point of view of the asker). Not all answers are helpful, not all askers come back to the site, when there are several answer who each helped a bit, which one should be accepted?

Comment: @KobyDouek If you define an unanswered question as a question without an answer, then it was answered as soon as you posted your answer, and it is no longer unanswered, even if the OP doesn't accept it.

Comment: Also - consider that amount of bounty questions - which have answers - but remain "unanswered". For me, as a user - the "unanswered" button renders useless.

Comment: @Servy Then, what is the purpose of posing questions as "unanswered" ? Stackoverflow can remove this status altogether.

Comment: @KobyDouek The purpose is to see questions that don't have a useful answer.  If you personally don't think that it's useful, then don't use it.  If *nobody* ends up using it, SE will see that and may consider removing it.

Comment: @Oded: "*The point of the accept is to indicate that "that answer helped me most" (from the point of view of the asker).*" If that were the case, then the UI wouldn't have such a strong distinction between questions with accepted answers and questions without accepted answers. The accept check means that, from the perspective of the OP, the problem has been resolved adequately. That doesn't mean that the best possible answer exists, but it does mean that if you're looking for questions without a satisfactory answer, you'd probably be better off looking elsewhere.